# PHP Quotation Calculator

Tags: php

newbie here...
Im trying to create a simple php quote calculator, I've got a quantity field and 2 lest menus.

What I'm trying to do is multiply the quantity by a assigned value of the one list item added to quantity multiplied by an assigned value of the other list item, no combination of the two list items will be the same.
I've got this to work fine except once one of the list items is the same the calculation is thrown off...

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['calculate'] ))
{
$type=$_REQUEST['type'] && $lam=$_REQUEST['lam'];
if($type=="One Side Colour" && $lam=="None")
{
$add1 = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
$res= $add1*.70+$add1*0;


}

if($type=="One Side Colour" && $lam=="One Side")
{
$add1 = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
$res= $add1*.70+$add1*.15;
}


if($type=="Two Sides Colour" && $lam=="None")
{
$add1 = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
$res= $add1*1.4+$add1*0;
}
```

the last "if" confuses the calculation

Any ideas to get around this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Firstly, I do not understand why you are using the logical operator `&&` when assigning variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, new to this so not sure whats the best way to go about it

Comment: Take a loot at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code fix ups:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['calculate'] )){
     $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
     $lam = $_REQUEST['lam'];
     $add1 = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity']; // Casts the value to Integer
     if($type=="One Side Colour" && $lam=="None"){
          $res = ($add1 * .70) + ($add1 * 0); // Unclear 0 * anything = 0
     }

     if($type=="One Side Colour" && $lam=="One Side"){
          $res = ($add1 * .70) + ($add1 * .15);
     }

     if($type=="Two Sides Colour" && $lam=="None"){
          $res = ($add1 * 1.4) + ($add1 * 0); // Another 0 issue?
     }
}
```

Added a  few `( )` to outline the order or operations. Also don't get why you multiply by 0...

**Edit**

After some of your comments, this would be condensed some:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['calculate'] )){
     $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
     $lam = $_REQUEST['lam'];
     $add1 = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity'];
     if($type == "One Side Colour") {
          $res = ($add1 * .70) + ($add1 * ($lam == "One Side" ? .15 : 0));
     } elseif($type == "Two Sides Colour") {
          $res = ($add1 * 1.4);
     }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Looked at your HTML and have a few suggestions:

```
<table width="450" cellpadding="5" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" name="quantity" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['quantity'])?$_REQUEST['quantity']:''); ?>">    Business Cards</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Number of Sides</td>
    <td>
      <select name="type">
      <?php
      $type = array(
           "One Side Colour",
           "Two Sides Colour",
           "One Side Black/White",
           "One Side Colour/Other Side Black/White"
      );
      foreach($type as $o){
           if(isset($_REQUEST['type']) && $_REQUEST['type'] == $o){
                echo "      <option selected='selected'>$o</option\r\n";
           } else {
                echo "      <option>$o</option>\r\n";
           }
      }
      ?>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lamination</td>
    <td>
      <select name="lam">
      <?php
      $lam = array(
           "None",
           "One Side",
           "Both Sides"
      );
      foreach($lam as $l){
           if(isset($_REQUEST['lam']) && $_REQUEST['lam'] == $l){
                echo "      <option selected='selected'>$l</option\r\n";
           } else {
                echo "      <option>$l</option>\r\n";
           }
      ?>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="Submit" value="calculate" name="calculate"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr><td>Price</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bolder;font-size: 20px;"><?php echo (isset($res)?"P$res":""); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

This will allow your form to retain the selections each time the price is calculated.

Comment: Thanks let me give this a try, will let you know shortly

Comment: Thanks silly me was just trying different things I've removed the 0 multiply on "none"

Comment: Hey Twisty you rock! the first code fix you gave me works great thanks so so so much , I've added all the other variables and all seems good, just one last quick question, is there any way to have the quantity remain in the field after "calculate"?

Comment: I suspect the answer is yes, but I have no reference to confirm this. Please clarify. What field?

Comment: Also, if this has answered your question, please click the checkmark to indicate an answer.

Comment: The Quantity field, have a look at the test page: http://www.crystaldigitalprint.com/Bcard-calc.php

Comment: `<input type="text" size="5" name="quantity" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['calculate'])?$_REQUEST['calculate']:''); ?>">`

Comment: For future questions, that example page would have been good to include up front. Or the HTML form that you're using as part of your code example.

Comment: sorry excuse my ignorance but where would i place this as the "<?php" is showing up in the field?

Comment: Within your index.php file, You can replace `<input type="text" size="5" name="quantity">` with what I posted in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['calculate'] )){
 $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
 $lam = $_REQUEST['lam'];
 $add1 = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity'];
 if($type == "One Side Colour") {
      $res = ($add1 * .70) + ($add1 * ($lam == "One Side" ? .15 : 0));
 } elseif($type == "Two Sides Colour") {
      $res = ($add1 * 1.4);
 }}
```

Also, I've created a calculator, regarding [auto transport quote](http://www.autotransportcity.com)
If you need any help and code of that calculator than contact me.